Вставленный на тильде фрейм не отображается при публикации
Когда вставляю на странице в тильде фрейм через блок html и публикую, отображается только граница, или вообще ничего не отображается.
Вот фрейм:
<iframe src="http://www.alfaplan.ru/iframe/" width="800" height="650" align="left">
</iframe>


Нет параметра align, есть text-align:
<iframe src="http://www.alfaplan.ru/iframe/" width="800" height="650" text-align="left">
</iframe>


к сожалению не помогло
